# Turning off the "activities" hotcorner at the top left?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

I am finding it hard to turn off the hotspots on the desktop (Ubuntu 18.04.2) at the top left corner that shows up with a miniature version of the windows I have available to switch to. The stuff I can think to search for like "activities hotspot ubuntu" are all too generic to get me there.

I checked gnome-shell extensions in Firefox, but I didn't see anything obviously it and am not very familiar with the interface yet. Does anyone know what to call this feature? I just want to turn it off because it false triggers all the time when I hit close buttons on a maximized application, and having two monitors makes this happen as well when on a second monitor that shows no floating taskbar.

Where are such configurations stored in the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `gnome-tweaks` (tweaks) and turn this setting to OFF...

[image]

Comment: My upvote doesn't show since I'm too new, but this worked great and gave me a desktop application to control my configuration settings again =) Thanks @heynnema!

Comment: @BrianNeltner you're very welcome!

Comment: This setting doesn't appear for me in Gnome 3.30.2. Has it been removed?

Comment: @JonathanHolvey Still shows for me with 3.32. What version Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Debian Buster. Could this be a Ubuntu only modification to Gnome?

Comment: @JonathanHolvey you could bring up `dconf` editor and search for `hot-corners`.

Comment: I also run debian buster and am facing the same problem. I tried searching for hot-corners in dconf-editor. No results came. The No Topleft Hot Corner extension suggested by @edvard in the next answer worked though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install No Topleft Hot Corner extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/